# Getting an error while creating a javascript object inside angular

Tags: javascript, angular, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the javascript code cors_upload.js [here](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/javascript/cors_upload.js) in my Angular 9 project to upload video to youtube. However, I am getting an error:

```
src_assets_js_cors_upload_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.MediaUploader is not a constructor.
```

Here are the things I've already done:

- I've already created a project and got the API key.
- I already ask for youtube upload permission and the user has granted it
- downloaded and included cors_upload.js file in src/assets/js folder.
- Included the CORS upload script in the angular.json as

  ```
  "scripts": [
    "src/assets/js/cors_upload.js"
  ]
  ```
- In the code I imported the functions in cors_upload.js as
- Below is my code that tries to create the MediaUploader object:

  ```js
  var uploader = new ytapi.MediaUploader({
    baseUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos',
    file: uFile,
    token: token,
    metadata: metadata,
    params: {
      part: Object.keys(metadata).join(',')
  }})
  ```

Inside cors_upload.js, MediaUploader is declared as a constructor:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @constructor
 * @param {object} options Hash of options
 * @param {string} options.token Access token
 * @param {blob} options.file Blob-like item to upload
 * @param {string} [options.fileId] ID of file if replacing
 * @param {object} [options.params] Additional query parameters
 * ...
 */
var MediaUploader = function (options) { 

... 

}
```

Comment: Well even though it is commented as a constructor it is still a function, have you tried this without using 'new' ?

Comment: I need an object to be returned so that I can call other methods on that. For example, the function with constructor takes information about file to upload, however, later, I need to call send method for the file to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was trying to create the javascript object from a service. That did not work. I moved the creation to component. Now, I can create the javascript object.

I declare the MediaUploader as a type before the component is declared

```
declare var MediaUploader any
```

Then in my code I can create the object:

```
var uploader = new MediaUploader(...)
uploader.upload()
```

I still would like to know how to create Javascript object from a service. Is it possible? If not, why? For now, in my code I can continue.

Comment: Please note that asking a question within the boundary of an actual answer to another question does not provide the visibility that the new question needs. Simply create a new question, providing complete and relevant context to it (thus making it self-contained) and, eventually, link it to your initial question and its corresponding answer.